# Can I style the Netlify CMS preview with Theme UI and/or Emotion?

Tags: emotion, netlify-cms, css-in-js, theme-ui

I have a Gatsby project that uses Theme UI and Netlify CMS.

How can I style the Netlify CMS preview pane with my Theme UI styles?

Netlify CMS doesn't support CSS-in-JS libraries:

https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/issues/793

Unlike Styled Components, it doesn't seem possible to convince Emotion to inject its styles into the Netlify iframe, either. There does appear to be some support for injecting raw CSS into the preview iframe:

https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/pull/1162

But so far I can't seem to figure out how to make any of this work together on my own.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this. I am using Emotion in my site as well. I don't want to create css separate css styles just for the templates

Comment: No sorry, I ended up getting fed up with Netlify and switching to another CMS.